# Segmentation 11 in Linux issue

Tags: c++, buffer-overflow

I am doing a buffer overflow problem and I trying to print hello world. Below is my code to 
but I am getting a segmentation 11 issue when I run this file with another one. "./executable < input.cpp(This is the file below). I am doing something wrong to solve a buffer overflow issue?

```
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;


main()
{
    printf("A");
    //00000b00
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

    printf("%c%c%c%c",0x00,0x0b,0x00,0x00);



}
```

Below is the actual code that I am trying to print hello world. Above is my input string.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
 int i;
unsigned int* p;

void f1() {

   int a=10;
  char str[4];

  cout << "Please enter a string:";
  while (!cin.eof()) {
    cin.get(str[i]);
    i++;
  }

printf("address of str is:%x\n",str);

  cout << "The string you entered is:";
    printf("address of a is:%x\n",&a);
  cout << str << endl;
}

void f2()
{
  cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

main()
{ 
  printf("The address of function f2:%08x\n",f2);
  f1();
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: This isnt forcing it to print Hello World  

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int i;
unsigned int* p;

void f1() {

   int a=10;
  char str[4];

  cout << "Please enter a string:";
  while (!cin.eof()) {
    cin.get(str[i]);
    i++;
  }

printf("address of str is:%x\n",str);

  cout << "The string you entered is:";
    printf("address of a is:%x\n",&a);
  cout << str << endl;
}

void f2()
{
  cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

main()
{ 
  printf("The address of function f2:%08x\n",f2);
  f1();
}

Comment: You should not mix `printf` and `cout`

Answer (score 1):

> I am getting a segmentation 11 issue when I run this file with another one.
>
> ```
>   ./executable < input.cpp
> ```
>
> I am doing something wrong to solve a buffer overflow issue?

Yes. Buffer overflow attacks don't work like that - dumping a bunch of C source code into memory does not magically make the machine compile and run it. To generalize wildly, the data you dump into memory must contain:

1. Padding to force the following data to lie in the right place in the stack
2. A replacement address in the location of the old return address, pointing to the following executable code
3. Some more padding, usually a "NOP slide"
4. Some executable code

Please read the classic "[Smashing the stack for fun and profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)", and keep in mind that you may have to disable some protections (non-executable stack, ASLR, stack canary) to get these exploits to work on a modern system.

Comment: Can you provide and example? I am roughly new to this.

Comment: Please read the paper I linked to. It's vastly more detailed than I can possibly explain here.

Comment: @user2402063 "Smashing the stack for fun and profit" is an essential publication in the topic, which must have been read at some point, but maybe its too deep water for you? You need to understand the difference between source code and machine code, source compilation. Machine code and assembly. A long way to go, but if you have patience you'll learn a lot. Also I hope that you won't use the knowledge for anything bad.

Answer (score 0):

- Use the `%x` modifier to print hexadecimal values

If this is a [C program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), then the use of `namespace std` makes no sense

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    puts("A");
    for (int i = 0x0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%x\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Op's post was updated:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int i = 0; //Initialise i

void f1() {
    int a=10;
    char str[4];

    cout << "Please enter a string: ";
    while (!cin.eof() && i < 4 ) { //Have a condition on length of string
            cin.get(str[i]);
            i++;
    }
    str[i] = '\0'; //Set the eof character at end of the string
    printf("address of str is: %p\n", str);
        printf("address of a is: %p\n", &a);
    cout << "The string you entered is: " << str << endl;
}

void f2() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
}

int main()
{
    printf("The address of function f2: %p\n", f2); //To print address use the %p option
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this is perhaps good advice, you haven't actually understood and answered the question being asked.